# non working session variable

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone please tell me why this session variable isn't being set?  When the login details are correct the offers page is re-directing users back to the index as though the session variable isn't set.

```
<?php
session_start();

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

mysql_connect("localhost", "******", "******") or die("Could not connect.");
mysql_select_db("*******") or die("Could not find database.");

if(($username=='')||($password==''))
{
echo"<script type='text/javascript'>;
alert('Please check and re-enter details');
window.location = 'index.php';
</script>";
}
$qry="SELECT*FROM login WHERE username = '$username' and password = '$password'";
$result=mysql_query($qry);

if(mysql_num_rows($result)==0)
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>;
alert('The username you have entered does not exist in our database.  Please check ad re-enter details.');
window.location = 'index.php';
</script>";

if(mysql_num_rows($result)> 0)
{
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
header('location: offers.php');
}
?>
```

offers.php code

```
<?php
if ($_SESSION["username"]=="") 
{
header ('Location: index.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: ^ at the very least sanitize your user input

Comment: Thankyou - Aarolama, so do i just replace mysql with mysqli then in the instances i have it above?

Answer (score 2):

You need to put `session_start();` at the top of your offers.php page.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding:

```
session_start();
```

to the top of offers.php